Powershell POSH-SSH or SSH.NET response time is too long
I am having trouble sending simple commands (echo $HOME or mkdir) through either PowerShell script via POSH-SSH or SSH.NET in .Net 4.8 code. The command does not respond for 4-minutes and sometimes takes as long as 8-minutes. POSH-SSH just times out waiting for response, even though it actually executes the command (mkdir creates the directory). This problem is specific to a Linux box that's running RedHat Linux 8.9 and OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1k.
Executing the command from the Windows built in OpenSSH client works fine. Also transferring SFTP files using SSH.NET works just fine 
I understand that POSH-SSH uses SSH.NET. I am trying to figure out if it's SSH.NET issue or the specific setup on the Linux box.
SSHD configuration on the target linux box
#   $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.103 2018/04/09 20:41:22 tj Exp $

Port 22
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV

PermitRootLogin yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys

PasswordAuthentication yes
PermitEmptyPasswords no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials no

UsePAM yes

X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no

PermitUserEnvironment yes
ClientAliveInterval 300
ClientAliveCountMax 0

AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS

Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server

Powershell script from Windows computer that times out on this specific computer:
$linuxHost = "10.120.2.127"
$user = "test"
$password = "password" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($user, $password)
$sshSession = New-SSHSession -ComputerName $linuxHost -Credential $credential -AcceptKey
$command = 'echo $HOME'
$response = Invoke-SSHCommand -SSHSession $sshSession -Command $command
$response.Output
Remove-SSHSession -SSHSession $sshSession.SessionId


I'm using Posh-SSH on a different context, from a Windows server to push commands to Cisco devices.
But I had very similar symptoms : Posh-SSH worked on most devices but Cisco's, where sometimes it would work great, sometimes it would take time and end up in timeouts.
In the end, I found an answer here :
https://github.com/darkoperator/Posh-SSH/issues/354
From Patrick92x comment there, you can revert to Posh-SSH 2.2 or replace the Renci.SshNet.dll in Posh-SSH 2.3.
I personally chose to revert completely to Posh-SSH 2.2 and my scripts work like a charm now, maybe one of the two solutions would do the job for you.

Interesting. I am using the latest SSH.NET and Posh. The SSH.NET has been overhauled since that post, and based on the last comment it suggests that it's been fixed in the earlier version. But, thanks for pointing this out. I'll try to poke into SSH.NET code and see if I can find something.
